# Fibonacci-like gap formula

Tags: code-golf, math, fibonacci

### Background

The recurrence of the Fibonacci sequence is defined as

$$
f(n+2) = f(n+1) + f(n)
$$

From this recurrence alone, the following *gap formulae* (recurrences relating three terms with certain amount of gaps) can be derived:

$$
f(n+4) = 3f(n+2) - f(n) \\
f(n+6) = 4f(n+3) + f(n) \\
f(n+8) = 7f(n+4) - f(n)
$$

<sup>You might have seen the \$n+6\$ formula if you have worked on Project Euler #2 hard enough :)</sup>

In general, for any \$a \in \mathbb{Z}^+\$ (positive integers), there exist unique integer coefficients \$\alpha, \beta\$ of the generalized gap formula

$$
f(n+2a) = \alpha f(n+a) + \beta f(n)
$$

which holds for all \$n\$.

We can generalize the Fibonacci recurrence itself too:

$$
f'(n+2) = uf'(n+1) + vf'(n)
$$

Then it can be shown that, for any \$a \in \mathbb{Z}^+\$ and \$u,v \in \mathbb{Z}\$, there exists a fully general gap formula with integer coefficients:

$$
f'(n+2a) = \alpha f'(n+a) + \beta f'(n) \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

Note that such a formula is not unique for some values of \$u, v, a\$.

### Challenge

Given the values of \$a, u, v\$, calculate the pair of values of \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$ in the equation \$\eqref{eq1}\$. You don't need to handle cases where the answer is not unique.

All three inputs are guaranteed to be integers. \$a\$ is strictly positive.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
For u = 1, v = 1
a = 1 -> alpha = 1, beta = 1
a = 2 -> alpha = 3, beta = -1
a = 3 -> alpha = 4, beta = 1
a = 4 -> alpha = 7, beta = -1

For u = -2, v = 3
a = 1 -> alpha = -2, beta = 3
a = 2 -> alpha = 10, beta = -9
a = 3 -> alpha = -26, beta = 27
a = 4 -> alpha = 82, beta = -81

For u = 3, v = -9
a = 1 -> alpha = 3, beta = -9
a = 2 -> alpha = -9, beta = -81
a = 3 -> undefined (not unique)
a = 4 -> alpha = -81, beta = -6561
a = 5 -> alpha = 243, beta = -59049
a = 6 -> undefined (not unique)
```

Comment: If I did my math right, \$\beta\$ is \$-(-v)^a\$, and \$\alpha\$ is the \$a\$'th element \$f(a)\$ of the sequence if we initialize \$f(0)=2, f(1)=u\$.

Comment: Suggested testcase: \$u=3,v=-9,a=6\$

Comment: Is the last \$a\$ in equation 1 supposed to be an \$n\$?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Right, it's n. Fixed.

Comment: Is the result unique for \$u = 3, v = -9, a = 6\$?

Comment: If \$f(0) = x, f(1) = y, f(n + 2) = 3 f(n + 1) - 9 f(n])\$, then \$f(6) = 729 x, f(12) = 531441 x\$. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMG1oiAxL8UhKDW5tKgoNS85NSQxKSc1ujot2iBWwdZWoUJHIS3aEMysBDHzFLQVjMBcYygPKKmrYAnixNYCVegoVOfpKBjoKBga1cb@/w8A "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") There isn't a unique formular between \$f(0), f(6), f(12)\$.

Comment: @alephalpha Oh, didn't realize that. I changed the challenge to allow solutions like yours (failing when the answer is not unique).

Answer (score 9):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 37 bytes

Saved 13 bytes thanks to @xnor.

```
(u,v,n)->[-(-v)^n,trace([0,1;v,u]^n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hczBCsIwDIDhu08RekogGVbnYYh7kdJBEScDCWVsBZ@@BhQP8yAkl598yWme5J7rCJeKKxdWkj4ISqFBeZnT9YZhz/5ceI2DUqwp58cTFaSHPE@6oPMMNg7U1qqDEd9JiRiCb5o20u7XyYHhuIGf9kfaRbeBlqT7Qgb70zKcItUX)

Comment: I don't know this Pari/GP, but I think it might be shorter to express the output as the trace and the negative determinant of `m`

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##nczBCsIwEATQu1@x5LQLu8VoPYjYHwkpBLFSkGUJbcCvjwHBcynMXAbeWMqzvKxOcK@4cmElGYKgFBqVl5weTwxH9rfCaxyVYk1m7w8qyACWZ13QeYYWB9raVgcT/iYlYgi@6/pIh01OTgznPbAhuf4hQ/vpGS6R6hc "Pari/GP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```python
lambda u,v,a:[(p:=u/2-(u*u/4+v)**.5)**a+(u-p)**a,-(-v)**a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUaFUp0wn0Spao8DKtlTfSFejVKtU30S7TFNLS88USCRqa5TqFoAYOroauiDhxNj/BUWZeSUaaRqGOkCoqcmFzDdC4xuj8U2Q@LpGOsYoBoAFjNAFjNEFgGb8BwA)

*¯2 thanks to @tsh*

Originally based on @tsh's answer (now removed due to no complex number support)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
Ø.,æ*ÆḊN,ÆṭƲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDD2dw8u0Drc93NHlpwOkdq49tun////GOrpG/40B)

Takes input as `[v, u]` on the left, and `a` on the right. Outputs as `[β, α]`

-1 byte thanks to ovs!

Uses xnor's formula that

$$\alpha = \operatorname{tr} \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ v & u \end{bmatrix}^a \right) \\
\beta = -(-v)^a = - \det \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ v & u \end{bmatrix}^a \right)$$

### How it works

```
Ø.,æ*ÆḊN,ÆṭƲ - Main link. Takes [v, u] on the left, a on the right
Ø.           - Yield [0, 1]
  ,          - Pair; [[0, 1], [v, u]]
   æ*        - Matrix power to a; Call this M
           Ʋ - Last 4 links as a monad f(M):
     ÆḊ      -   Determinant of M
       N     -   Negated
         Æṭ  -   Trace of M
        ,    -   Pair; [-det(M), tr(M)]
```

Comment: \$(-v)^a\$ is the determinant of the matrix (from xnor's comment on the PARI answer), which allows for 12: [`Ø.,æ*ÆḊN,ÆṭƲ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDD2dw8u0Drc93NHlpwOkdq49tun////GOrpG/40B)

Comment: @ovs Nice catch, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 77 bytes

```javascript
(u,v,a)=>[A=(F=n=>n<2?n^m:u*F(n-1)+v*F(n-2))(a+a,m=0)/F(a),F(a+a,m=1)-A*F(a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcxBDoIwEIXhvSeZgalKqyYai2HTSxhNGgSigdaI9PoViTvGzObNt/gfNti@fN2fb@H8rYq1jjBQIIs6PxcajHY6d0d5ctfuMCQGnMgwDdOQiGBTS51e48qARTK/P0NRJF@5xNK73rfVsvUN1JDReIiLuUpWFaubmQpJiglPLHlWPM/bisSeaU8seVY8/2lved6NHD8)

Let

$$ f_1\left(0\right)=0 \\ f_1\left(1\right)=1 \\ f_1\left(n+2\right)=u\cdot f_1\left(n+1\right)+v\cdot f_1\left(n\right) $$

Calculate

$$ p=f_1(2a) \\ q=f_1(a) $$

Let

$$ f_2\left(0\right)=1 \\ f_2\left(1\right)=0 \\ f_2\left(n+2\right)=u\cdot f_2\left(n+1\right)+v\cdot f_2\left(n\right) $$

Calculate

$$ r=f_2(2a) \\ s=f_2(a) $$

We have

$$ p=\alpha\cdot q \\ r = \alpha \cdot s + \beta $$

Solve

$$ \alpha=\frac{p}{q} \\ \beta=r-\alpha \cdot s $$

---

Try to undelete this question since all failed testcases currently known had been been excluded from the question. Maybe this one is correct, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 59 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 52 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(u,v,a)c((p=u/2-(u^2/4+v+0i)^.5)^a+(u-p)^a,-(-v)^a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYwxCsMwDEX3nkTCUtPKydAhVzGEgMGLY0Lk67smkyP@8HlveGeLa4ua9ysdGZQqbbgDlFUnYdAg0@yq@yQM7wXD5kC59CcGrv2xlTPlCyJ8qQ/xNbIY9obngVnIPwK3ECu8FWPDE/8ejVuIFb3R/g)

Based on [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s formula and [@PyGamer0's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236697/55372).

Outputs complex numbers - for pretty integers add 4 bytes for wrapping result in `Re`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0L‚©IF®øδ*O}Å\O¹θ(Im(‚
```

Port of [*@cairdCoinheringaahing*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236707/52210), but without matrix power/multiplication, trace, nor determinant builtins. It uses a slight modification of *@xnor*'s formula:

\$\alpha = \operatorname{tr} \left( \begin{bmatrix} u&v\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}^a \right) \\
\beta = -(-v)^a\$

Inputs as `[u,v]` and `a`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fwOdRw6xDKz3dDq07vOPcFi3/2sOtMf6Hdp7boeGZqwGU@/8/2lhH1zKWywQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeW6rX@ajhnmJtofXHF6trnN4r1J0qU5ZrG304f2xSrW1hzcc3muvpPCobZKCkn1lQqhL2H8Dn0cNsw6tjHA/tO7wjnNbtPxrD7fG@Eee26ERkasBlPqfUKx0bqPt4f0K5zYBSSWd/9HR0YY6hrEgpABlGiGYxgimCZipawQSM0RiGyGxjZHYEPXGOrqWMPUQthESG1mNaWwsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
0L          # Push [1,0]
  ‚         # Pair it with the (implicit) input-pair: [[u,v],[1,0]]
   ©        # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
    IG      # Loop the second input `a` - 1 amount of times:
      ®     #  Push the matrix from variable `®`
       ø    #  Zip/transpose it; swapping rows/columns
        δ   #  Apply double-vectorized over the two matrices:
         *  #   Multiply them together
          O #  And then sum each inner-most list
     }Å\    # After the loop: pop the matrix and push its main diagonal
        O   # Sum it together
¹           # Push the first input-pair again
 θ          # Pop and only leave the last item (`v`)
  (         # Negate it
   Im       # Take it to the power of the second input `a`
     (      # Negate that again
‚           # Pair the two integers together
            # (after which this pair [α,β] is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
ＮθＮη⊞υ²⊞υθＦ⊖Ｎ⊞υ⁺×θ§υ±¹×η§υ±²Ｉ⟦⊟υ±Ｘ±ηＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY27DsIwDEV3viKjI7UDRQyICcFSCVUZ2BBDaE1TKU3aPIC/D654qAOefO1zdGslXW2lTqk0QwxV7K/oYOTbxTwryiJ6BTFjxWyfuJt1DA5YO@zRBGxgLnLO2RcWOno4dT16GDO2C6Vp8Dk9KmxlQFgSnLE3oP4BBZ@G2l1nAuylD3AWdoDIf4iwD2r9BEX3I5o2UD2JF3JTWrF8w9Ypv@sX) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses @xnor's formula.

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `u` and `v`.

```
⊞υ²⊞υθ
```

Push `2` and `u` to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｆ⊖Ｎ⊞υ⁺×θ§υ±¹×η§υ±²
```

Calculate `a-1` more terms so that the last term is now the `a`th term.

```
Ｉ⟦⊟υ±Ｘ±ηＬυ
```

Remove and output the `a`th term, then calculate the power using the remaining length which is now `a`.